# Installing SVN username password issue

Tags: authentication, svn

I'm installing SVN with Apache 2.2 on windows 2003 everything seems good but when I try to login no username/password works.

Here is some info
I load this module in httpd.conf

`LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so`
and in `svnserv.conf` I have

```
[general]
anon-access=read
auth-access=write

password-db=passwd
authz-db=authz
```

In the `passwd` file:

```
[users]
harry=harry
sally=sally
```

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be that you need to generate the password file using [htpasswd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/programs/htpasswd.html). Storing unencrypted passwords isn't a good thing!

Comment: This is correct Apache assumes the password file is is created via htpasswd. Either reformat the password file or use the svn protocol with the built in svn server...

Comment: Note that this only applies if you're using HTTP Authentication with Apache - see the user guide for more info: http://svnbook.red-bean.com

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this isnt't technically an answer to the question you've asked, but you should try installing [Visual SVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/), which takes care of all of these headaches for you.  Setting up an SVN server is much easier with this tool on Windows than it is to do by hand.

Comment: I tried that and it works, but the reason i'm trying to install the none visual is that I also want to understand it as I may install it on Linux at some point.